# I want to create views dynamically and show them in the middle of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

```
    tv = new TextView[10];

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpFirst = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpFirst.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lpFirst.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tv[i] = new TextView(this);
        tv[i].setId(i + 1000);
        tv[i].setText("" + tv[i].getId());
    }
    rl.addView(tv[0], lpFirst);
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv[i-1].getId());
        tv[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
        rl.addView(tv[i], lp);
    }
```

here is my code
I want tv[1] ~ tv[9] placed right side of tv[0] but they placed left top side.
I don't know what is problem.

Comment: You're using the same `lp` object for each additional view. Try making a new one in the loop. Also, `setID` isn't reliable with a hard-coded number. You can `View.generate...` one

Comment: You have to define what is going wrong and define an specific question

Answer (score 0):

Just place a LinearLayout inside the container RelativeLayout in your XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
```

and get that container by id, and add each child to it